# awk include column value in pattern

Tags: awk

I am looking for a way to pattern match against another column in awk. For example, I wish to find rows for which the value in column 4 is nested in column 5.

Performing `awk '$4 ~ /$5/'` doesn't work, as the dollar sign is interpreted as part of the regular expression. How do I get the column 5 value into this pattern match!

Many thanks!

Comment: give us sample input lines and expected output... remove the `//` around `$5`...

Comment: Do you want to check for substrings, or is column 5 actually a regular expression?

Comment: Thanks, removing the // did it.

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking for literal match, not regex; you can use

```
awk 'index($5,$4)' file
```

will print the lines where $4 is a substring of $5.

Answer (score 1):

```
> awk '$2 ~ $1' <<< "field another_field"
field another_field
```

this will print lines when `$2` contains the value of `$1`